# How to define the matrix product in accelerate-haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix, accelerate-haskell

I am trying to define a typesafe matrix computation library on top of accelerate, partly for educational purposes, partly to see whether this is a practical approach.

But I am completely stuck when it comes to define the product of to matrices properly - i.e. in a way GHC accepts/compiles my code.

I have had a few tries, which were variations of this:

`Linear.hs`

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import qualified Data.Array.Accelerate as A

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Array.Accelerate ( (:.)(..), Array
                             , Exp, Shape, FullShape, Slice
                             , DIM0, DIM1, DIM2, Z(Z)
                             , IsFloating, IsNum, Elt, Acc
                             , Any(Any), All(All))
import           Data.Proxy

newtype Matrix (rows :: Nat) (cols :: Nat) a = AccMatrix {unMatrix :: Acc (Array DIM2 a)}
(#*#) :: forall k m n a. (KnownNat k, KnownNat m, KnownNat n, IsNum a, Elt a) =>
    Matrix k m a -> Matrix m n a -> Matrix k n a
 v #*# w = let v' = unMatrix v
               w' = unMatrix w
           in AccMatrix $ A.generate (A.index2 k' n') undefined
          where k' = fromInteger $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy k)
                n' = fromInteger $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)
                aux :: Acc (Array (FullShape (Z :. Int) :. Int) e) -> Acc (Array (FullShape (Z :. All) :. Int) e) -> Exp ((Z :. Int) :. Int) -> Exp e
                aux v w sh = let (Z:.i:.j) = A.unlift sh
                                 v' = A.slice v (A.lift $ Z:.i:.All)
                                 w' = A.slice w (A.lift $ Z:.All:.j)
                              in A.the $ A.sum $ A.zipWith (*) v' w'
```

The error `stack build` gives me is

```
.../src/Linear.hs:196:55:
    Couldn't match type ‘A.Plain ((Z :. head0) :. head1)’
                   with ‘(Z :. Int) :. Int’
    The type variables ‘head0’, ‘head1’ are ambiguous
    Expected type: Exp (A.Plain ((Z :. head0) :. head1))
      Actual type: Exp ((Z :. Int) :. Int)
    Relevant bindings include
      i :: head0 (bound at src/Linear.hs:196:38)
      j :: head1 (bound at src/Linear.hs:196:41)
    In the first argument of ‘A.unlift’, namely ‘sh’
    In the expression: A.unlift sh

.../src/Linear.hs:197:47:
    Couldn't match type ‘FullShape (A.Plain (Z :. head0))’
                   with ‘Z :. Int’
    The type variable ‘head0’ is ambiguous
    Expected type: Acc
                     (Array (FullShape (A.Plain (Z :. head0) :. All)) e)
      Actual type: Acc (Array (FullShape (Z :. Int) :. Int) e)
    Relevant bindings include
      v' :: Acc (Array (A.SliceShape (A.Plain (Z :. head0)) :. Int) e)
        (bound at src/Linear.hs:197:34)
      i :: head0 (bound at src/Linear.hs:196:38)
    In the first argument of ‘A.slice’, namely ‘v’
    In the expression: A.slice v (A.lift $ Z :. i :. All)

.../src/Linear.hs:198:39:
    Couldn't match type ‘A.SliceShape (A.Plain ((Z :. All) :. head1))’
                   with ‘A.SliceShape (A.Plain (Z :. head0)) :. Int’
    The type variables ‘head0’, ‘head1’ are ambiguous
    Expected type: Acc
                     (Array (A.SliceShape (A.Plain (Z :. head0)) :. Int) e)
      Actual type: Acc
                     (Array (A.SliceShape (A.Plain ((Z :. All) :. head1))) e)
    Relevant bindings include
      w' :: Acc (Array (A.SliceShape (A.Plain (Z :. head0)) :. Int) e)
        (bound at src/Linear.hs:198:34)
      v' :: Acc (Array (A.SliceShape (A.Plain (Z :. head0)) :. Int) e)
        (bound at src/Linear.hs:197:34)
      i :: head0 (bound at src/Linear.hs:196:38)
      j :: head1 (bound at src/Linear.hs:196:41)
    In the expression: A.slice w (A.lift $ Z :. All :. j)
    In an equation for ‘w'’: w' = A.slice w (A.lift $ Z :. All :. j)

.../src/Linear.hs:198:47:
    Couldn't match type ‘FullShape (A.Plain ((Z :. All) :. head1))’
                   with ‘(Z :. Int) :. Int’
    The type variable ‘head1’ is ambiguous
    Expected type: Acc
                     (Array (FullShape (A.Plain ((Z :. All) :. head1))) e)
      Actual type: Acc (Array (FullShape (Z :. All) :. Int) e)
    Relevant bindings include
      j :: head1 (bound at src/Linear.hs:196:41)
    In the first argument of ‘A.slice’, namely ‘w’
    In the expression: A.slice w (A.lift $ Z :. All :. j)
```

I have consulted the documentation of [Accelerate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/accelerate-0.15.1.0/docs/Data-Array-Accelerate.html), and I am also reading [accelerate-arithmetic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/accelerate-arithmetic) which has a similar aim but does not use `TypeLits` in order to assert the array/vector dimensions.

I also tried to make a vanilla version (i.e. without my own matrix type), in case my types were wrong, which I believe is suffering from the same misconception about the usage of `slice`. I am including this just for completeness' sake, I can add the error messages,but I chose to omit them as I believe they do not relate to the problem above.

```
(#*#) :: forall a. (IsNum a, Elt a) =>
    Acc (Array DIM2 a) -> Acc (Array DIM2 a) -> Maybe (Acc (Array DIM2 a))   
v #*# w = let Z:.k :.m = A.unlift $ A.arrayShape $ I.run v
              Z:.m':.n = A.unlift $ A.arrayShape $ I.run w
           in if m /= m'
                 then Nothing
                 else Just $ AccMatrix $ A.generate (A.index2 k n) (aux v w)
          where aux :: Acc (Array DIM2 a) -> Acc (Array DIM2 a) -> Exp DIM2 -> Exp a
                aux v w sh = let (Z:.i:.j) = A.unlift sh
                                 v' = A.slice v (A.lift $ Z:.i:.All)
                                 w' = A.slice w (A.lift $ Z:.All:.j)
                              in A.the $ A.sum $ A.zipWith (*) v' w'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is actually correct. Unfortunately the typechecker isn't smart enough to figure it out, so you have to help it:

```
let (Z:.i:.j) = A.unlift sh
```

becomes

```
let (Z:.i:.j) = A.unlift sh :: (Z :. Exp Int) :. Exp Int
```

The critical thing here is that `A.unlift :: A.Unlift c e => c (A.Plain e) -> e` but `A.Plain` is an associated type family (and therefore non-injective) so the type `e` cannot be determined without a type signature, and `e` is required to select an instance to use for `Unlift c e`. This is where the 'ambiguous type' errors come from - it is really `e` that is ambiguous.

---

You also have an unrelated error. `aux` should have the type

```
aux :: (IsNum e, Elt e) => ...
```

or

```
aux :: (e ~ a) => ...
```

in the latter case the `a` is the one in type signature of `(#*#)` so it already has the constraints `IsNum, Elt`